# Counterexample $(V^\perp )^\perp = V$ when $V$ is not a closed subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, inner-products

Let $(X, \langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and induced norm $\rVert \cdot \lVert$.
We know that if $V\subseteq X$ is a closed subspace, then  $(V^\perp  )^\perp = V$, where $V^\perp$ denotes the orthogonal complement with respect to the inner product.

Now let $X:= L^2([0,1], \mathcal L^1, \lambda^1)$ be the set of Lebesgue square integrable functions on $[0,1]$.

Define $V:= \{\varphi \in X: \varphi(0) = 0 \}$. Clearly, $V$ is a subspace of $X$.

Now I showed that $V \neq(V^\perp  )^\perp$, i.e. we have a strict inclusion, by explicitly constructing a function that is in $(V^\perp  )^\perp$, but not in $V$.

To understand this better I tried to show that $V$ is not closed with respect to the $L^2$-norm. So I tried to construct a sequence $(\varphi_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ such that $\varphi_n(0) = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ but $\varphi_n \to \varphi$ with $\varphi(0) \neq 0$. However this was kind of tedious dealing with the square in the integrand. Is there an easy way to construct a sequence or some other, better/cleaner option to disprove closedness?

Comment: Usually $L^2$ is defined as equivalence classes of functions that differ on a set of measure zero. Hence it doesn't make sense to speak of the value of an element of an element of $L^2$ at a point.

Comment: But if you consider some other space where it does make sense to talk about functions' values at points, i would expect the set of functions vanishing at a point to be a closed set.

Comment: For an example of a non-closed subspace, we could take the span of a basis, like the trig functions.

Comment: @ziggurism $\{\varphi \in C[0,1] : \varphi(0) = 0\}$ is not closed as a subset of $(C[0,1], \|\cdot\|_2)$ as an example of Ice sea shows.

Comment: @ziggurism you are correct, I actually meant the subspace of continuous functions where it does make sense to talk about values at a point. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @lappen68 continuous functions are not complete. this is not a Hilbert space.

Comment: I see. My question was just intended to find a counterexample that $\{\varphi \in C[0,1]: \varphi(0) = 0\}$ is not closed in $(C[0,1], \lVert \cdot \rVert_2)$ which Ice sea constructed and therefore answered my question. Good thing that you pointed out my mistakes though.

Comment: @ziggurism So one more question: Say we have a inner product space $X$ which is not complete and a closed subspace $V \subseteq X$. Is the completeness condition necessary, i.e. can it happen that $(V^\perp)^\perp \neq V$?

Comment: @lappen68 I continue to believe that the set $\{\phi\colon \phi(0)=0\}$ actually _is_ closed, in any reasonable space where this set can be defined. Ice sea's example sequence converges pointwise to a function with $f(0) = 0$. It doesn't show that the set is not closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a complete inner product space from Lebesgue integrals, you must consider equivalence classes of functions defined up to sets of measure zero. Consequently predicates like $\phi(0)=0$ do not make sense for elements of $L^2([0,1])$.

We could instead ask the question about a space where evaluation does make sense, like the continuous functions $C([0,1])$ with uniform convergence or the space of pointwise convergence $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$. Note that the space of continuous functions is not complete in the $L^2$ norm, so this is no longer a Hilbert space.

In both cases, the evaluation function (a function which takes a function and returns its value at a fixed input) $\text{ev}_0$ is continuous, hence the set $V=\{\phi\colon \phi(0)=0\}$ is the preimage of a point under a continuous function $V=\text{ev}_0^{-1}(0)$, hence it is closed. You cannot show this set is not closed, because it is in fact closed.

The example sequence given by Ice sea does not show that the set is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$, because it converges pointwise to a function with $\phi(0)=0$. It doesn't show that the set is not closed in $C([0,1])$, because it does not converge uniformly. And it does not show that the set is not closed in $L^2([0,1])$ because the set is not defined there.

For an example of a set that is not closed, just think of things which include only finite combinations, but not limits. For example, the space of polynomial functions $P([0,1])$ makes sense as a subset in any of these three function spaces. $e^x$ is the limit of a sequence of polynomials. Hence $e^x$ is in $(P([0,1])^\perp)^\perp$ but not $P([0,1])$.

Or consider the function space $L^2([-1,1])$. This space can be split into even functions $E=\{\phi\colon \phi(x) = \phi(-x)\}$ and odd functions $O=\{\phi\colon \phi(x) = -\phi(-x)\}$. The both subspaces are closed. A basis for the even functions is $\cos(n\pi x)$. The function $\left|1-x\right|$ is even. It's perpendicular to all odd functions. It's in $(\langle\cos(n\pi x)\rangle^\perp)^\perp,$ but not $\langle\cos(n\pi x)\rangle,$ since it's not a finite linear combination of cosine functions.

Comment: I can make sense of what you are saying, however, here are two remarks/questions: 1) Why do we need uniform convergence? He shows that $f_n$ converges towards a function that is in $C[0,1]$ and $f(0) \neq 0$, how is that not sufficient to show that the set is not closed? 2) Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647817/orthogonal-complement-examples/647858#647858 Daniel Fischer gives an example of a non complete inner product space where $V$ closed but $V \neq (V^\perp)^\perp$

Comment: @lappen68 You don't have to use uniform convergence. But you do have to choose _some_ topology. I considered $L^2$, pointwise, and uniform. In Ice Sea's example, we have $f_n(0) = (1-0)^n-1$. The limit of this sequence is $0$, not $-1$. Ice sea's example is not showing what you want.

Comment: @lappen68 Looking at Daniel Fischer's example, I see that I must be mistaken about $(V^\perp)^\perp = \bar V$ in any inner product space. I apologize. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: You know the equivalent classes. But you didn't know what is dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Then one of you has a contradiction in his answer.

Comment: @lappen68 what contradiction?

Comment: Ice sea still claims that the space is not closed (he edited his answer).

Comment: @lappen68 i guess icesea is talking about the space of functions with $L^2$ topology, but without identifying functions equal almost everywhere. This space is not Hausdorff and somewhat weird. It is not a Hilbert space. It is possible that the evaluation map is not continuous on this space, which would resolve the contradiction.

Comment: I see.I will think about it a little more.

Answer (score 3):

For any subset $S$ of a inner product space, $S^\perp$ is closed(use continuity of the inner product). So $V^{\perp\perp}$ never equals to $V$ when $V$ is not closed.

Comment: That was already a known fact for me, I just wanted to construct an explicit counter example to understand it better.

Comment: So, construct an explicit example of a non-closed set $S$.  Say, the complement of the origin.  Then compute $S^{\perp \perp}$.

Answer (score 2):

First, if the element in your space is considered to be an "equivalent classes", then $V=L^2[0,1]$. Obviously, it is closed. To make you problem well-defined, we consider $L^2[0,1]$ to be space of functions instead of equivalent classes.

It is easy to disprove the closendess  in this case.
 $f_n(x)=(1-x)^n-1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then $f_n(x)\to f(x)=-1$ in $L^2[0,1]$  as $n\to\infty$. In addition, $f_n(0)=0$.  To see the convergence, we only need the dominated convergence theorem. First $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ a.e. and they are are both bounded from above. So $f_n\to f$ in $L^2[0,1]$. i.e., 
$$
\int |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2 dx \to 0
$$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. I have submitted an answer which explains why.

Comment: @ziggurism Dominated convergence is enough

Comment: @Icesea you’re talking about convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: @ziggurism It is good enough to show that $
\int |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2 dx \to 0
$ Anyway, this problem is NOT well-defined if this space is usual L^2 space

Answer (score 1):

Take the “prototype” of all Hilbert non finitely generated but separable space, namely $l^2$, the space of (complex) sequences $(a_n)$ such that
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}|a_n|^2
$$
converges (for a real Hilbert space just use real sequences). The Hilbert form is
$$
\langle (a_n),(b_n)\rangle=\sum_{n\ge0}\overline{a_n}b_n
$$
(switch the conjugation if you use the opposite convention about linearity).

The subspace we want to consider is $V$ consisting of the “eventually null” sequences, that is all $(a_n)$ such that there exists $N$ with $a_n=0$ for every $n\ge N$.

It's easy to prove that $V$ is dense in $l^2$. Thus $V^{\perp\perp}=l^2$. Indeed, given $s=(a_n)\in l^2$, define
$$
s^{(m)}(n)=\begin{cases}
a_n & n\le m\\
0 & n>m
\end{cases}
$$
Then $s^{(m)}\in V$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty}s^{(m)}=s$ (check it), so the statement about density follows. Since $V$ is dense, $V^{\perp}=\{0\}$.